# Make Doctrine query in ProjectConfiguration class

Tags: symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I need to execute a Doctrine Query in my project configuration class.
I tried to put my code in the setup method but it cant find the classes.

Do i need to register Doctrine Autoload manually or something?.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just how you said - you have to define ProjectConfiguration class with manual autoloading registration because ProjectConfiguration runs before it:

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . ''.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'lib'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'vendor'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'symfony'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'autoload'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
sfCoreAutoload::register();

class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration {
```

I have my projects set with symfony cloned internaly in vendor path, change your path how you need to.